# UISearchDisplayController cancel button not refreshing headers and index

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, cancel-button

I have a table view, with a long list of strings. There are headers for each section, an index along the right hand side, and a search button.
This has been implemented programmatically, using a UISearchDisplayController, (i.e. not in IB).

When the search button is activated, I hide the headers (in `titleForHeaderInSection`), and hide the index (in `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView`), by asking
`if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive])`

The problem is, when the cancel button is clicked, the headers and index remain hidden, at first. I tried (in `searchBarCancelButtonClicked`) to call `[self.tableView reloadData]`, but that doesn't work.

I have a `[self.tableView reloadData]` in my `viewWillAppear`, which helps in one way: if I select a row, push another view onto the stack, and then go back to this table, the headers and index are there as wanted.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that sometimes, when [tableView reloadData] doesn't work, doing this will:

```
[tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

For whatever reason, sometimes the table view gets into such a state that it must wait until the next iteration through the run loop before the reload will be effective.

Comment: You're welcome!   And also, sometimes, when you want to do a row insert/delete animation together with the reload, put in a delay greater than zero (0.3 works well) because the reloadData will cancel the animation I've found.